# Can I use a crash dump from an x64 C++ exe to find the line that threw an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I want to generate a crash dump on an unhandled exception. I would like to be able to load that crash dump in Visual Studio and see the line that threw the exception in the call stack. I can do this if I compile using Win32. I can't do this if I compile using x64.

**Is it possible to have a crash dump that includes `willThrow() Line 14` if I compile using x64?**

Here is a simple example program and two call stacks, one from a Win32 exe and the other from an x64 exe (Compiled with VS2015 IDE using v120--Visual Studio 2013):

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <Windows.h>

LONG WINAPI UnhandledExceptionFilter(
    _In_ struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo
)
{
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

void willThrow()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("Throw");
}

void main()
{
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(UnhandledExceptionFilter);

    try
    {
        willThrow();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**x64 Call Stack**  <-- Basically useless

```
    KernelBase.dll!RaiseException() Unknown
>   msvcr120d.dll!__RethrowException(EHExceptionRecord * pThisException) Line 1234  C++
    msvcr120d.dll!__CxxCallCatchBlock(_EXCEPTION_RECORD * pExcept) Line 1296    C++
    ntdll.dll!RcFrameConsolidation()    Unknown
    BlankVS2013Project.exe!main() Line 22   C++
    [External Code]
```

**Win32 Call Stack**  <-- Helpful

```
    KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16() Unknown
    [External Code] 
>   BlankVS2013Project.exe!willThrow() Line 14  C++
    BlankVS2013Project.exe!main() Line 23   C++
    [External Code]
```

**Update**

MS Connect Link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3114436/call-stack-broken-between-win32-and-x64-c-builds

MSDN Forums: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/60584558-19e7-4c1c-94dc-f5234203210f/can-i-use-a-crash-dump-from-an-x64-c-exe-to-find-the-line-that-threw-an-exception?forum=vclanguage

Comment: Hmya, it is somewhat inevitable that every programmer's nicety turns into something that will be exploited by a black hat.  x64 code generation exclusively uses the equivalent of /SAFESEH.  A nicety got lost.  Surely you can get ahead by not writing catch-em-all-throw code.

Comment: @HansPassant If I compile in Win32 with /SAFESEH, I can see a valid call stack. If I catch a specific exception (std::runtime_error), I'm still not pointed in the right direction. That seems to break try/catch/rethrow entirely if we ever want any hope of being able to debug our exception. If this works in Win32 with /SAFESEH, why should this not work for x64? If it's a nicety lost with x64 intentionally, must we rely on an UnhandledExceptionFilter as our only place to do cleanup if we want a good call stack (because a try/catch/rethrow will obfuscate the call stack)? Seems wrong/like a bug.